# Vertical alignment of two adjacent minipage in a 2-column document (created with paracol)

Tags: tables, align, vertical-alignment, minipage, tabularray

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\columnwidth}
        {\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont Huge Header\par}
        {\Huge Huge Sub-Header\par}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \\ \lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to align the two minipage in the right column at the top of the page, as here following:
[image]
**How to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [t] option aligns the first baseline, and the default for tabular is [c] which aligns the center.  So the first baseline of the first minipage is aligned the to center of the tabular.

This uses `\raisebox` to move the baseline to align with the first line of the first column.  Note that `\ht\strutbox` is font size dependent.  `\topskip` will move it too high.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
    \noindent
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\columnwidth}
        {\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont Huge Header\par}
        {\Huge Huge Sub-Header\par}
    \end{minipage}}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}}\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}% show baseline
    \\ \lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: A very interesting approach @John, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi John, Is there a simple way to adjust the vertical distance between the top margin of the page and both ```\raisebox``` (only on the right column)? I tried to add ```\vspace{1cm}``` between ```\switchcolumn``` and ```\noindent```, but nothing happened...

Comment: `\vspace` is absorbed at the top of the column.  Use `\vspace*` instead.  OTOH, the first optional argument of `\raisebox` can be used to add height, if it bigger than the default (in this case >`\ht\strutbox`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, because the alignments `[t]` in the minipages align the baselines of the first line in the left column with the center of the tabular on the right. You want the tops to be aligned, and for that to happen you need to give the right tabular also a `[t]` positioning, **and** you have to sneak in `\vspace{0pt}` at the top on both sides.

```
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\columnwidth}
        \vspace{0pt}
        {\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont Huge Header\par}
        {\Huge Huge Sub-Header\par}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\columnwidth}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|r|l|}
            \noalign{\vspace{0pt}}
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
            First & Second\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Pieter! This is a simple way for me! I think both of your and John's methods are nice and I don't know which one to accept :-)